# Android N_Perform the fingerprint matching in a (TEE) or on a chip with a secure channel to the TEE

Tags: android, security, hal, android-fingerprint-api

Anyone could help me explain some points below

1. TEE (Trusted Execution Environment) is mandatory in Android N.Could you please help me to provide more detail information about how this feature to be implemented on Android N devices.
2. How to perform the fingerprint matching in a Trusted Execution Environment (TEE) or on a chip with a secure channel to the TEE. What is mechanism and what are need to use?

I have read follow links but I still not so clear.

[Hardware-backed Keystore](https://source.android.com/security/keystore/)

[Trusty TEE](https://source.android.com/security/trusty/index.html)

[Fingerprint HAL](https://source.android.com/security/authentication/fingerprint-hal.html#fingerprint_matching_flow)

[Authentication](https://source.android.com/security/authentication/index.html)

Comment: May help: https://www.blackhat.com/docs/us-14/materials/us-14-Rosenberg-Reflections-on-Trusting-TrustZone.pdf

Comment: Thanks I'll see it

Comment: whether you  implement ?